# I have problem with Godaddy Forwarding service: e.g. example.com to www.example.com

Tags: godaddy, forwarding

Problem with Godaddy Forwarding service: e.g. example.com to www.example.com 
problem with forwarding domain e.g. example.com to www.example.com over Godaddy Forwarding service 
I have problem with forwarding domain e.g. "example.com" to "www.example.com"  over Godaddy Forwarding service

1. My problem:

   - I have domain e.g. example.com
   - I want redirect www.example.com to example.com over Godaddy Forwarding service
   - I set "A" record: Host=@ Point to= "MY IP ADDRESS"
   - I set "CNAME" record: Host=www Point to=@
2. Status:

   - my www.example.com point correctly to "MY IP ADDRESS" and my site working at url www.example.com correctly
   - when I type URL example.com in web browser I do not get redirection to www.example.com
3. I try these below solution but for me it is not working. 
   Forwarding service at godaddy working when I forwarding to other domain,  e.g. wwwm.mydomain.com: 
   http://community.godaddy.com/groups/domains-management-and-services/forum/topic/about-cname-and-no-www-redirecting/?sid=635309&sp=1
   http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/422
4. I test "Godaddy Forwarding service" with various setting and domain that I have in Godaddy and I wait more than 48h but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS does not do redirection unless your using a specific web forwarding service, if DNS is just pointed at your web server you need to configure the correct redirection on your web server and GoDaddy forwarding will not work within the same domain as its designed for forwarding old domains to new ones, not non-www to www redirection

if your hosting on Linux and Apache this is as simple as following the instructions detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157255/how-to-redirect-non-www-to-www-urls-using-htaccess

Comment: Thanks you for your answer Anthony, I think that you correctly detect a problem: "GoDaddy forwarding will not work within the same domain"
I will redirect it on my server.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach to this issue, which is where you want example.com and www.example.com to forward to the same web server is as follows. This is not specific to godaddy services.

DNS configuration:

- Create an A record for example.com, which points to IP of your web server.
- Create a CNAME record for www.example.com which points to example.com.

Doing this the other way around (i.e.creating a CNAME for your top-level domain) is not recommended.

Web server configuration:

- Ensure your webserver accepts requests for both www.example.com and example.com

Optional, if you prefer that http://example.com redirects to http://www.example.com or vice versa - you create a redirect within your webserver from one to the other. This is canonicalization is not required, but some people prefer to do it. How you configure it depends on your web server.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer Barry, I think that is a problem in Antony statement: "GoDaddy forwarding will not work within the same domain"
I will redirect it on my server.

Comment: redirecting from www to non or non to www is good to prevent possible search engine ranking issues